# Waves and linear dependence on space and time

Tags: waves, terminology

Any function that depends on space and time through the combination $\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}-\omega t $, namely a function $$f(\vec{r},t)=g(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}-\omega t)$$ where g is an arbitrary function of a single real variable, represents a perturbation that propagates in the direction of $\vec{k}$ with a velocity $v=\omega/k$. For sure this tipe of function can be considered a wave, if the broadest definition of wave is adopted: *"wave = moving perturbation"*.

But do all types of wave have such space-time dependence? Is this the only way to implement a function that describes a moving perturbation?

Comment: when you describe various systems from each level mathematically / algoritgmically, what do they all have in common?

Answer (score 0):

> But do all types of wave have such space-time dependence?

Certainly not. General form of wave equation is :

$$ \Box u=0, ~~~(1)$$

where,

$$ \Box ={\frac {1}{c^{2}}}{\frac {\partial ^{2}}{\partial t^{2}}}-\nabla ^{2} ~~~(2)$$ is
a [d'Alembert operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert_operator)
.

So any function $u(\vec r,t)$ which satisfies eq. 1, has wave properties. Such functions should be many.

Comment: But all solutions of the wave equation are linear combinations of the ones given by the OP. For example, we can take them to be monochromatic plane waves.

Comment: But do they have to be linear ? On the other hand most basic requirement for a wave is periodicity of some amplitude over space and time. Usually this is seen as a plane wave, i.e.  $\sin(x)$ function. But does most common trigonometric functions are the **only** periodical functions? I feel there should be a huge set of them too. Overall,- it's not the point what common linear wave equation solutions do we have now, but it's about what kind of different solutions we **can have** at all ? I feel such question is not analyzed much.

Comment: I changed the text to be more clear. Note that waves, from what I know, can be solution of different differential equations other than d'Alambert equation. Moreover the definition "wave = moving perturbation" does not imply a space or time periodicity of the perturbation itself: think to a moving single light pulse that moves in space.

Comment: About a single moving perturbation - you are right,- that periodicity is not a necessary attribute. But, about a different general wave differential equations I suppose you may be wrong. As far as I know d'Alembert operator is most general description of waves. And Btw this operator equally well suits to single pulse traveling, i.e. for example [for stress pulse in a bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation#Stress_pulse_in_a_bar) : $$ \ddot u(x,t)={\frac {E}{\rho }} \nabla ^{2} u(x,t). $$ So I think that this operator can define any perturbation in space-time. What can be more general?

Comment: An example, from what I understood, could be the Klein-Gordon equation: $(\Box + m^2)\phi = 0$ .

Comment: Well, Klein-Gordon equation extends d'Alembert operator by one additional term $\mu^2$. Probably because gravitational waves depend on mass amount. This only confirms the idea that d'Alembert operator is super-universal and can be used for describing any wave nature.

Comment: Schrödinger equation also uses some form of modified d'Alembert operator, which is in that case : $$ \Box \to a {\frac {\partial }{\partial t}}+b\nabla ^{2} -V(\mathbf {r} ). $$ Not exactly a d'Alembert operator of course, but very similar to it, except that it uses first order time derivative (instead of second in d'Alembert original form) and adds potential operator.